# assignment of url_for to variable and using it as parameter in render_template, doesn't work

Tags: python, flask

I'm facing a problem with url_for, i build the index page with html code that i put into a variable in the views.py, this variable is passed as parameter in render_template function, in the index page with `{{ content }}`i can get the html code from the function and display well almost all the data, when the page was loaded in the href i don't see the correct route, but i see `<a href="url_for('detail')">` instead of `<a href="detail">`.

This is the views.py

```
for dog in dogs:
    url_detail = url_for('detail')
    htmlDog = htmlDog + '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mt-3">
        <div class="animal_block mx-2"><img alt="animal image" src="' +  
        str(dog[6]) + '" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" />
        <div class="text-center">' + str(dog[0]) + '</div><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 

        labore et dolore magna aliqua...</div><div class="text-center">
        <a href='  + url_detail + '>look detail</a></div><span 
        class="animal_id">1</span></div></div>'

def home():
     return render_template(
        "index.html",
        content = htmlDogs,
        )

I have to call some function to encode htmlDog or use something different of render_template?
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask's `url_for` rely on request context, you can't put it outside the view function, try to move the for loop into the `home` function.

Besides, instead of join HTML code in Python, you should write the for loop directly in the template (`index.html`) with Jinja syntax. For example:

```html
<body>
{% for dog in dogs %}
    Put your html code here.
    You can generate URL like this: <a href="{{ url_for('detail') }}">
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

also, remember to pass the `dogs` variable with render_template:

```py
@app.route('/')
def home():
     return render_template("index.html", dogs=dogs)
```

Read [Jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. I was getting crazy about url_for.